# How can I correct for multiple comparisons in two-way non-normal data (without using Bonferroni)

Tags: multiple-comparisons, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test, two-way

I'm struggling to carry out statistical analysis on my cell viability assay. The assay is widely used (it's called resazurin or alamarBlue assay), but I don't think it is analysed correctly in the literature (I'll explain why below).

Here is my hypothesis: decreasing the amount (i.e. knockdown) of my gene of interest and exposing the cells to radiation will reduce cell viability more than radiation alone or knockdown alone.

To test this, I knockdown (KD) the gene in the cells (using 2 different methods). I then expose them to increasing doses of radiation. 48 hours later, I add a compound (resazurin) that changes color depending on how many viable cells there are. The intensity of the fluorescence is directly proportional the number of viable cells. I use a plate reader to measure fluorescence and get relative fluorescence units (RFU).

Here is a visualisation of the data:

[image: line graph showing three lines. One for Control (no knockdown), one for knockdown using method 1 (KD_1), and the last line is for knockdown using method 2 (KD_2). The x-axis is radiation doses: 0, 3, 6, and 10 Gy. The y-axis is relative fluorescent units, which are proportional to the number of viable cells. The median and SEM are shown for each data point.]

[Image description: line graph showing three lines. One for Control (no knockdown), one for knockdown using method 1 (KD_1), and the last line is for knockdown using method 2 (KD_2). The x-axis is radiation doses: 0, 3, 6, and 10 Gy. The y-axis is relative fluorescent units, which are proportional to the number of viable cells. The median and SEM are shown for each data point.]

For most of the conditions, I have 4 biological replicates, for some only three, and for one condition (KD_1 with 3 Gy), I only have two biological replicates.

Now, in previous literature employing this experiment, authors normalize the control and the knockdowns to their respective 0 Gy (no radiation) values, and get percentage of cell viability from that. Then, they do an ANOVA, followed by Tukey-Kramer to get corrected pairwise comparisons. However, I can't do that, because the data is neither normally-distributed, nor homoscedastic (at least mine isn't). I tested this based on [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/39-regression-model-diagnostics/161-linear-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r-essentials/) article.

This is what my QQ plot looks like for testing normality:
[image: QQ plot showing that residuals do not follow the same straight line as a normal distribution]

--

This is what my scale-location plot for testing homoscedasticity looks like:
[image: scale-location plot showing that variability of the residual points decreases with the value of the fitted outcome variable]

So: now I'm stuck. I can do Kruskal-Wallis in place of ANOVA (but I'm not even sure it works for two variables [knockdown and radiation]), but that won't tell me anything about what's actually changing. Ideally, I want to do pairwise comparisons, which puts me in a situation where I have to correct for multiple testing. Tukey-Kramer assumes normality and homoscedasticity, though, as far as I know. And I don't want to do Bonferroni because it's way too conservative. I don't know what other options there are.

Also, say I stick to Mann-Whiteny and only do two comparisons to avoid correcting for multiple tests: my final plot will have % viability (relative to 0 Gy for each of Control, KD_1, and KD_2) on the y-axis, rather than RFU, so do I extrapolate the p-value of the Mann-Whitney I did on the RFUs, or do I need to test the percentages separately?

As you can probably tell, I'm very lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information, or would like me to post the data.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the title accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that your analytical problem relates to multiple testing. Instead, you need to think about how to decide whether there is a linear ('additive') or non-linear interaction between knockdown and radiation effects on viability. If it is non-linear then it might be synergistic and thus, I suppose, interesting.

Comment: As shown, the data look consistent with no interaction between radiation and knockdown beyond the knockdowns causing a reduction in the pre-radiation viability. Synergistic interactions are often biologically interesting, but they are not always straightforward to demonstrate.

Comment: The data look heteroscedastic to me, particularly if the numbers beside points in your hetero graph indicate the y-values of those points. (It's a dreadful graph if that is the case, as it disguises the very thing you are looking for!). Many measurements of cell cultures scale geometrically, so consider using the square root of the RFU in the analysis.

Comment: The values beside the points are row-numbers (so you can find the observation's row in your data set). The spread seems to be decreasing with increasing mean; if the aim is to stabilize variance, taking square root of the response would tend to make that effect worse.

Comment: @Majd You cannot interpret the QQ plot when you have heteroskedasticity.

Comment: @MichaelLew @ Glen_b Thank you both for teaching me more about this. I didn't know a QQ plot can't be interpreted with heteroscedastic data, and, yes, a synergistic relationship would be the perfect thing to test! I have evidence from another experiment that there is interaction between radiation and knockdown (based on a MLR model [the data for that experiments satisfied the linearity, normality, and homoscedasticity assumptions]). I'm not sure how to test it here, though, with the data looking the way it does . Thanks for your help so far, and any more pointers are appreciated!